# First Web Scrape - How can I get to a child DIV within a DIV?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to Python and am attempting to give my first go at a web scrape using BeautifulSoup. I'm following with a Youtube video whereby you get the title, price, ratings of a graphics card from Newegg.

I'm able to get to the first graphics card, and the div called 'item-container', which has all the info about the card. Within this div there are two other child divs at the same level. And the second one is what I'm trying to access.

When in the child div(item-info), I tried getting the variable I assigned to that, and use the . operators so that it can drill down to the next div below it, and then ultimately, the 'a' class below that. This is when I get an error.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card'

#opening connection and grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#does the html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})

container = containers[0] #this returns a the first 'item-container'

item_info = container.findAll("div",{"class":"item-info"})

#this is when the error comes into play
brand = item_info.div
```

The error it's giving is this:

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_graphiall() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item.
```

Comment: use `item_info = container.find("div",{"class":"item-info"})` to get the first element, or you can follow the same logic as you did with `container = containers[0]` => `brand = item_info[0].div`

Comment: That did the trick! Something that simple was causing me so much issue!

Answer (score 0):

from comments:

use `item_info = container.find("div",{"class":"item-info"}`) to get the first element, or you can follow the same logic as you did with `container = containers[0] => brand = item_info[0].div`

attributable to @PRMoureu

Comment: @PRMoureu if you wish to gain rep for this drop a line here and I will delete so you can post as answer.